# Distribuir programas sem perder o caminho/path na hora da execução

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-basic-6

Boa noite amigos, estou com uma dificuldade, meu projeto é um botão que quando você clica ele abre uma executável, quero publicar meu projeto junto com o programa sem perder o caminho na hora de executar em outra maquina..

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que ambos executáveis estejam na mesma pasta, você terá que usar `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, um exemplo de estrutura de pastas:

```
projeto
├── programa.exe
└── resources
    ├── app1.exe
    ├── app2.exe
    └── app3.exe
```

Tendo um estrutura semelhante a está, você pode criar uma função para chama-la sempre que for executar um app em particular, exemplo:

```
Function ChamarApp(app As String)
    Dim Filename As String

    Filename = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\resources\" & app

    Shell("Start.exe " & Filename, vbHide)
End Function
```

Para usar basta chamar, como no exemplo:

```
ChamarApp("app1.exe") 'Chama o primeiro aplicativo
ChamarApp("app2.exe") 'Chama o segundo aplicativo
ChamarApp("app3.exe") 'Chama o terceiro aplicativo
```

Answer (score 0):

Em vb6 você utiliza o comando [App.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fc353bw2(v=vs.90).aspx) para retornar o caminho do executável.